# How well does the Dell Inspiron Duo work?

Tags: dell, inspiron

I am thinking seriously to buy a dell inspiron duo tablet/pc, but as a ubuntu lover I don't know if it works well or which features will be lost.

Has anyone worked with this tablet?? any suggestions??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working ;p
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGlPvnW6mgU

Answer (score 1):

It works, but make sure to test your system to make sure all the hardware works, and it doesn't have the Dell power loss issue before putting Ubuntu on it. If you don't, then Dell tech support's sock puppets in India will act like Ubuntu caused the problem and it'll take a lot of arguing to get them to even consider it being a hardware problem.

You'll know you've got the issue if it randomly switches off at the BIOS screen.

There's a thread in the Ubuntu forums about getting the touch screen working; it seems like the driver requires manual installation and a little (fairly simple) configuration. The only thing that doesn't seem to work at all is the accelerometer, which doesn't have a driver as of this writing. If you like Kubuntu, there's even a script under development to switch between Plasma Desktop with the keyboard unfolded, and Plasma Netbook when its in tablet mode.